# WPF combobox like popup

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a custom popup that will be similar to the combobox one.

I used a Toggle button as the header and a Popup for the content.

```xml
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Popup, Path=IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
    ...
</ToggleButton>
    
<Popup x:Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False">
    ...
</Popup>
```

This works great except one case. When the popup is opened and I click on the `ToggleButton` again, the popup disappears but then reopens right after.

Looks like when I clicked on the toggle button, Popup detected that the mouse click is outside of the popup so it closes itself and sets `ToggleButton.IsChecked = false`. Then the click sets `IsChecked = true` so the popup opens again.

Edit: In such case I would like the popup to close just like the behavior of a Combobox.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locate the popup on top of the button so the user can't click on the button. You can do it easily with `Placement` and so on.

Comment: I would actually want the toggle button to close the popup just like a combobox. sorry for not being clear

Comment: @Steve It *appears* to do that. When you click on the disabled toggle button, the popup closes. I have done this in production code and the user experience is exactly what they expect -- and exactly what you're asking for. It works like a combo box. In fact IIRC I wrote our combo box template exactly the same way.

Comment: saved my day twice